# Precedence of overloaded cast operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In the code below, I would expect to get a compiler error if more than one cast operator is defined because of the ambiguity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct A
{
    operator const char*() { return "hello world\n"; }
    operator float()       { return 123.0F; }
    //operator int()         { return 49; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    std::cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Instead, as long as only one numeric cast operator is defined then it compiles with no errors, no warnings, and the numeric cast is used in preference to the `operator const char *()`. The order of the declared operators makes no difference.

However if `operator int()` and `operator float()` are both defined then I get what I expected from the start:

> 'operator <<' is ambiguous

Are there precedence rules for casts, or why does the compiler choose the numeric cast by default? I do understand that I should explicitly state which cast I mean, but my question is on the default choice the compiler makes.

---

Edit: Using compiler MSVC 2010

Comment: I would not rely on there being a precedence. Type what you mean. Simply use a explicit cast. `ss << static_cast<T>(a);`

Comment: I compiled your example and g++ gives me "error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'ss << a'". So, at least g++ is working as expected.

Comment: This seems to be compiler dependent. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I guess in this case it depends on the declarations of `operator<<` that the implentation provides (if it has any freedom there, anyway). For example non-templates are preferred over templates and so on. So in the end it is at least implementation-defined. What implementation is it, by the way?

Comment: g++ and Oracle CC give me an ambiguity error, IBM xlC prefers the void* member overload (applied to the result of operator const char*).

Comment: Edited to include that this is with MS Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @acraig5075: My answer is wrong. Please unaccept it so I can delete it.

Comment: Do you get an error message, when compiling with option `/Za`? Maybe this bug report [std::string assignment should probably be ambiguous and fail to compile, but is not](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/743685/std-string-assignment-should-probably-be-ambiguous-and-fail-to-compile-but-is-not) explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conversions are ranked according to § 13.3.3.1 of the C++ Standard. In particular, user-defined conversion sequences pertinent to your example are regulated by § 13.3.3.1.2/1:

*"A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence. [...] If the user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion function (12.3.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function."*

All conversions sequences here involve:

1. a fictitious conversion to the source type of the implicit object parameter of the conversion function;
2. a user-defined conversion;
3. an identity conversion to the input type of `operator <<`.

These conversion sequences all have the same rank. Thus, **the call should be ambiguous**. If it is not, for me it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Your answer is misleading, since there shouldn't be any *"second standard conversion"* involved here anyway, since the user-defined conversion converts directly to the neccessary type. So yes, the call should be ambiguous, but not for the reason you give in your third paragraph.

Comment: @ChristianRau: if i understand correctly what 13.3.3.1.2/1 says, a user-defined conversion is *always* a three-step conversion, where the first step can be fictitious: "the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object parameter of the conversion function."

Comment: Yes, but the initial and second standard conversions can just be no-ops. And in this case the target types are already reached by the (middle) user-defined conversion. So yes, they all have equal rank, but not because integer- float- or pointer-conversions have equal rank (this doesn't matter here), but because they all just involve the same initial standard conversion, followed by a user-defined conversion, **followed by the same (no-op) second standard conversion**.

Comment: @ChristianRau: you are actually right. I edited my answer based on your feedback, thank you